# Pentaho Error: Duplicate entry for non primary key

Tags: mysql, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

Hi guys i am new into `pentaho`, using `pentaho kettle version 7.1` and `mysql jdbc driver` version is  5.1.43. I have two same table in different database. Let's called `db1` is first database which hosted in production and `db2` is another database which hosted in development. Both `db1` and `db2` have same table called `dashboard_user`. Table `dashboard_user` has primary key `id` which is `autoincrement`. But the problem is when i attempt to copy value from production to development without delete existing data in development it returns like below:

> 017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - Connected to database [localhost] (commit=1000)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : Because of an error, this step can't continue: 
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - Error inserting row into table [dashboard_domains] with values: [sonar.id], [2016/07/17 07:27:31.000000000], [2017/07/25 08:08:26.000000000]
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - 
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - Error inserting/updating row
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - Duplicate entry 'sonar.id' for key 'index_dashboard_domains_on_domain'
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - 
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - 
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:385)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.processRow(TableOutput.java:125)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - Error inserting/updating row
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - Duplicate entry 'sonar.id' for key 'index_dashboard_domains_on_domain'
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - 
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.insertRow(Database.java:1321)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:262)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  ... 3 more
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'sonar.id' for key 'index_dashboard_domains_on_domain'
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2494)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.insertRow(Database.java:1288)
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 -  ... 4 more
>   2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=0, U=0, E=1)

it says:

> Error inserting/updating row 2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - Duplicate entry 'sonar.id' for key 'index_dashboard_domains_on_domain' 2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - 2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - 2017/08/16 15:13:02 - Table output.0 - at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:385)

`sonar.id` is username and not primary key, i was wondering why i could not transfer data ? but returning error which says duplicate keys ?

Answer (score 0):

It tries to do exactly what it tells you: insert a key with a duplicate id.

First solution is to delete (truncate) the output table before to insert the record again.

Second solution is to use an `Output table` with an Error handler: Put a `Dummy` step and select Error handling when defining the hop/arrow. This step will receive all errors, including duplicates.

Third solution is to make an incremental load with a [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete). The step is named [Joins/Merge Row (diff)](http://wiki.pentaho.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=22184555). You specify the reference (existing) data and the new incoming data, as well as the key to compare. Kettle then create a new field containing 'new', 'deleted', 'identical' or 'updated' from which you can filter out only the new data.

[image]